# TortoiseSVN Diff in the main right click menu

Tags: windows, windows-registry, svn, tortoise-svn

Hello Super (smart) users,

I use TortoiseSVN for version control. Usually, I use the right click menu for the file in Windows explorer. I mainly use SVN **commit**, **update** and **diff**. SVN Diff is located in a additional submenu (with few millisecond of waiting).

Is it possible to edit **Registry key** to add **SVN DIFF** in the main menu (just like Commit and Update)? I may help me save some time and give little more convenience.

Here is the image of what I am talking about. Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a rightclick on Explorer and open the TortoiseVN options

[image]

After saving the option, when you do a righclick on a file in Explorer, the Diff option is displyed were you want it:

[image]

Comment: oh wow...I am so sorry. it was so simple. I should have done a due diligence before. Marked as the answer.